# mdfind with single quotes

Tags: macos, bash, applescript, spotlight

I'm writing an applescript that will find a file for me based on the filename including extension. The script uses mdfind in the bash shell. I've had luck with this construction:

mdfind name:'"filename.avi"'

But it breaks down when my filename has a single quote (apostrophe) in it like so:

mdfind name:'"MST3K - S05E13 - The Brain That Wouldn't Die.avi"'

I've tried to escape the single quote with a backslash but no dice:

mdfind name:'"MST3K - S05E13 - The Brain That Wouldn\'t Die.avi"'

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and inspect the result, so you see how you should quote it with apostrophes, you should of course remove the double quotes. And you should also open the man page for mdfind, to see how the name command is peformed.

```
set q to quoted form of "MST3K - S05E13 - The Brain That Wouldn't Die.avi"

set res to do shell script "mdfind -name 'MST3K - S05E13 - The Brain That Wouldn'\\''t Die.avi'"
```